# HTML страница плохо отображается при печати

Tags: html, css, pdf, print, печать

Есть html страница с 4 чеками, в браузере получилось вроде неплохо (2 сверху и 2 снизу), но когда я пытаюсь распечатать такую страницу (предполагалось что распечатается на одном листе A4 4 чека) получается такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Как мне правильно расположить мои чеки в html, чтобы их можно было распечатать одним A4? Мой html код:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--


span.customer{white-space: pre;font-family:Impact;font-size:30.0px;color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none}
div.customer{font-family:Impact;font-size:30.0px;color:Black;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none}

-->
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="background.png">
<div style="transform:rotate(90deg)">
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-49px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-18px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 13px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 44px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 75px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<img src="background.png">
<div style="transform:rotate(90deg)">
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-49px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-18px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 13px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 44px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 75px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
</div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="background.png">
<div style="transform:rotate(90deg)">
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-49px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-18px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 13px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 44px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 75px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<img src="background.png">
<div style="transform:rotate(90deg)">
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-49px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top:-18px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 13px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 44px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:-168px;top: 75px" class="customer"><span class="customer">Some Text</span></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте это `@media print{ html, body { width:  fit-content; height: fit-content; margin:  0; padding: 0; } }`. По результатам отпишитесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте медиа запросы для печати:

```
@media print{
    /*здесь нужные стили*/
}
```

Однако встает вопрос, а сколько пикселей на странице А4? По разному, зависит от dpi (количество точек на дюйм) принтера. Поэтому прежде чем печатать физически, пользуйтесь предварительным просмотром)

Comment: 21cm = 793,7px. Пиксели виртуальны и не привязаны к разрешению принтера. Иначе бы миллионы страниц с текстом в 12px невозможно было бы напечатать

Comment: Загляните как-нибудь в pdf-файл текстовым редактором. Там как раз для А4 указан размер 794 :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen почитайте про dpi и принтеры на досуге)

Comment: А вы про CSS :)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html “In fact CSS requires that 1px must be exactly 1/96th of an inch in all printed output”